# How to print out the numbers that meet a condition?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

I was wondering how to print out the actual numbers that meet the requirement of `i%3==0`, cause currently I only know how to print out the amount of numbers that meet said requirement. Any suggestions ?

My code:

```
public static int TAsk()
{
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            count++;
    }
    //Console.WriteLine("There are {0} numbers divisible by 3 between 1 and 100.", count);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Before/after doing `count++`, print `i` from that if-block.

Comment: oh, but how come if I print out the i after the count++ it just goes from 1 to 100 ?

Comment: Put the body of that `if` in a {block} because it deals with multiple statements when you add in a print statement as well.

Comment: I see I see thx alot

Answer (score 1):

Before/after doing `count++`, print `i` from that `if`-block.